# EXTBASE: How to get current page uri in extbase controller?

Tags: controller, request, uri, extbase, uribuilder

How to get uri of current page in extbase extension controller? In case I need to send current uri via email or save it to database for later use or statistics.

Answer (score 13):

You can use this line:

```
$this->uriBuilder->getRequest()->getRequestUri()
```

Example:

```
public function newAction(Tx_YourExtension_Domain_Model_YourModel $yourModel = NULL) {
    $this->view->assign('yourModel', $yourModel);
    $this->view->assign('url', $this->uriBuilder->getRequest()->getRequestUri());
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Though following is more efficient..

```
 $this->controllerContext
  ->getUriBuilder()
  ->reset()
  ->setTargetPageUid(int PAGE_UID)
  ->setArguments(array ARRAY_VARIABLE_OF_ADDITIONAL_ARGUMENTS)
  ->buildFrontendUri();
```

OR

Include UriBuilder object

```
/**
 * UriBuilder
 *
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Web\Routing\UriBuilder
 * @inject
 */
protected $uriBuilder = NULL;
```

Get URL using following

```
$this->uriBuilder
    ->reset()
    ->setTargetPageUid(int PAGE_UID)
    ->setArguments(array ARRAY_VARIABLE_OF_ADDITIONAL_ARGUMENTS)
    ->buildFrontendUri();
```

For Base Uri

```
$this->request->getBaseUri()
     OR
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->baseUrl
```

Comment: I don't see how this is more efficient.